# Docker swarm: declare an env-file from configs

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-secrets

I'm using compose file to declare my stack.

Within my compose file , I have several services and configs:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  myservice:
    image: myImage
    env_file : ......
    secrets:
      - cert.pem
configs:
  myEnvFile.list:
    name: myEnvFile
    file: myEnvFile.list
```

I want a workaround to re-use my configs file "**myEnvFile.list**" as an env file for my service.

**NOTE:** I don't want to pass with `env_file`  , as it recommands me to get files under each server of my servers , which I want to evitate, by centralizing it within "**configs**"

**Suggestions?**

Comment: Without a workaround, the way to go seem to use `docker config create` https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/configs/

Comment: The matter is not how to declare configs , but how to reuse their contents as en var inside containers @pdem